# IN VS EXIST sub queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

why does this work:

```
select custid, companyname
from sales.customers as c
where exists
(select orderid
from sales.orders as o
where c.custid = o.custid and o.orderdate = '20070212')
```

and this does not

```
select custid, companyname
from sales.customers as c
where custid in
(select orderid
from sales.orders as o
where c.custid = o.custid and o.orderdate = '20070212')
```

and when should I use what?

Comment: is it throwing an error or just returning nothing?

Comment: You need to supply sample data and example output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first query with the `exists` clause, it actually doesn't matter what you are selecting in the subquery, it just checks for the existence of the row in the subquery.  You could have selected `NULL` and it would work just as well:

```
select custid, companyname
  from sales.customers as c
 where exists (select null -- doesn't matter what you select
                 from sales.orders as o
                where c.custid = o.custid 
                  and o.orderdate = '20070212')
```

However, in your 2nd query with the `in` clause, the column being returned in the subquery is significant.  And though we don't know anything about your table structure and data, the column names make it pretty clear that you are selecting the wrong column in the subquery (`... where custid in (select orderid ...`). (Why do you compare customer ids to order ids?)

In fact, if you are going to use an `in` clause, it doesn't really make sense to also have a correlated subquery, it's kind of redundant. So it would probably look like this instead:

```
select custid, companyname
  from sales.customers as c
 where c.custid in (select o.custid
                    from sales.orders as o
                   where o.orderdate = '20070212')
```

Obviously, I don't know much about your data, but for this type of query, using the `exists` clause with a correlated subquery will normally be the better choice.  As with anything, check and compare the different execution plans and choose the best one.

As for general guidelines about when you would select `in` vs. `exists`, there are tons of great articles out there already, including on SO. Not a difficult search on google.

Comment: A comment for the OP:  I would highly encourage you *not* to use `SELECT NULL` for the correlated subquery, because i think it is confusing for `NULL` to mean that something exists.  I usually use `SELECT 1`.

Comment: @Gordon: Heh. I suspect most people would agree with you. I personally copied the `where exists(select null` style from Oracle's Tom Kyte. To [quote him](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:442029737684#5692820553867): *"I find select null to be semantically more meaningful.  You are NOT selecting anything really -- so say that."*  I've always agreed with that and have stuck with that style ever since. But I get your point as well.